# Is there any way to parse ISO8583 message in which the bitmap is masked or doesn't have any Bitmap?

Tags: adapter, payment, middleware, iso8583, j8583

I am working on a bi-directional adapter which applies some transformations on ISO8583 messages and send it to another side. But one side of adapter sends the messages which don't have bitmap.

```
2019-01-26 13:38:27,774  ChannelServerEndpoint.run()  Can't parse request  1804179121190126120635801
```

In real scenario after MIT(1804) I should had 8 or 16 hex digit as Bitmap. like this one:

```
Sending request: 163726, ISO Message: <br/>**18040030010000000000163726190123065952831**<br/>
TYPE: 1804<br/>
F  11(NUMERIC): 163726 -> '163726'<br/>
F  12(DATE12): 190123065952 -> '190123065952'<br/>
F  24(NUMERIC): 831 -> '831'<br/>
```

I am using J8583.

```
try {
            log.debug(String.format("Parsing incoming: '%s'", new String(
                    data)));

            // incoming message
            IsoMessage incomingMessage = messageFactory.parseMessage(data, NetworkInterfaceConfiguration.MESSAGE_HEADER_LENGTH);

            //  System.out.printf("Message TYPE: %s", messageType);
            MessageTransformer transformer = new  MessageTransformer(incomingMessage);
            transformer.run();

            if (transformer.getIsoMessage() != null) {
                System.out.println("We are before assigning transformations");
                transformedMessage = transformer.getIsoMessage();
            } else {
                log.error("Transformation is failed.");
            }

            IsoMessageUtil.printIsoMessage(transformedMessage);
            log.info("Firing Message to Dist....");
            ChannelClientEndpint.fireMessage(transformedMessage);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            log.error(String.format("Can't parse request %s", new String(data)));
            throw new UnknownError(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("Writing response", ex);
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            throw new UnknownError(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to parse an ISO8583 message without a bitmap AND a spec for the type of each field. If you know which fields you are supposed to receive and of what type they are, you need to configure the `MessageFactory` that way, and manually insert a bitmap into your data so it can be parsed as a regular ISO8583 message.